# Static secure server with node and connect

Tags: node.js

i need a static [https](/questions/tagged/https) [server](/questions/tagged/server). I choosed [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) because of its portability. In this way i can just save a `.js` script in the repo and have the server easily runned on windows and linux machines.

After some research, i ended up with the following solution using [connect](/questions/tagged/connect):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var connect = require('connect');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('ryans-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('ryans-cert.pem')
};
connect(options, connect.logger() , connect.static(__dirname))
    .listen(443);
```

Where the self signed certificates are generated using [this guide](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.9/api/tls.html#tLS_). Unfortunaltely, this nice [node](/questions/tagged/node) script is not working properly. Indeed, i'm getting a `107` error on chrome, and a "The connection was interrupted" error with firefox.

What is missing to this setup in order to have the simple server working?

---

#### Notes (answering to comments)

- why i say node is portable: compared to other web servers like apache or nginx, i can keep a simple script in the repo root, instead of a configuration file somewhere in the filesystem. the position of such configuration file would change between different systems
- why i need a secure level: because some of the contents rely on other contents that will not be allowed (asynchronously) if the origin domain is not secure
- the certificate is needed, but you can always sign your own for development purposes and keep it in the repo together with the server script

Comment: I don't see how JavaScript is more portable then any other scripting language. :)

Comment: I think he means that with Node you don't need a seperate web server to run it, like a Rails stack for Ruby or Apache for PHP, Python, etc. You do still need to have Node installed (and most likely npm), so I still agree that most languages are just as portable as others.

Comment: This may be a naive question, and it may be because its early for me, but why do you need an ssl secured static server? If it is just static there is no interaction between the client and server other than the static page, so there is no transmission of personal/sensitive information.

Comment: does it work if you don't use a certificate?

Comment: @NickMitchinson, you need to serve static files with ssl if the pages that are refering to those static elements are served with ssl. If you don't use ssl for the static elements, the browser will complain ("the page you are requesting is trying to connect to unsecure elements blah blah")

Comment: Ah fair enough that makes sense. I was imagining that the OP wanted to host a complete static site, not serve static content for other sites.